# How to create a chart from a GridControl

Tags: winforms, charts, devexpress, xtragrid

Prior asking this question, i read similar post such as:

- [Create chart from DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324195/create-chart-from-datagridview)
- [Get data from DataGridView to Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005460/get-data-from-datagridview-to-chart)
- [Creating chart from datagridview C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542298/creating-chart-from-datagridview-c-sharp)
- [making chart from datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347734/making-chart-from-datagridview)
- [C# Using data from DataGridView in a Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604667/c-sharp-using-data-from-datagridview-in-a-chart)

But i am still unable to show my datagridview data to a my chart. I am using xtragrid and Xtracharts controls to achieve my task and in my datagridview, i have some unbound columns.

here is the code i have tried to use

```
private  void ChartData()
        {
            Series S = new Series();
            LineSeriesView view = new LineSeriesView();
            S.View = view;
            ProdchartControl.DataSource = ProdgridControl.DataSource;
            S.ArgumentDataMember = "Prod Date";
            S.ValueDataMembersSerializable = "Orange prod";
            ProdchartControl.SeriesDataMember = "ProdID";
            ProdchartControl.Series.Add(S);

        }
```

your assitance will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ChartControl provides built-in integration with the GridControl component (see  [Integration with a Data Grid, Vertical Grid, Tree List or List Box via ControlRowSource](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/119224/Controls-and-Libraries/Chart-Control/Providing-Data/Integration-with-a-Data-Grid-Vertical-Grid-Tree-List-or-List-Box-via-ControlRowSource)).

For an example with unbound fields, refer to the [How to display data from an unbound column displayed in the grid control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T707931/how-to-display-data-from-an-unbound-column-displayed-in-the-grid-control) ticket.